# How to check if dynamic select query returns zero records and return markup

Tags: forms

I have a custom Drupal form that is populated with a dynamic query. How do I return an 'alert' if no results are returned? There has to be a better way of doing this than what I have come up with.

This is what I have so far and it throws an error when a record is returned because it continues processing the actual form.

Query:

```
public function loadByPID($pid = null) {    
  $database = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('default', 'newDB');    
  $query = $database->select ('Person');
  $query->condition('personid', $pid);
  $query->fields('Person', ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']);
  $results = $query->execute();
  return $results;
}
```

Call to query:

```
$results = $this->repository->loadByPID($pid);
```

The form and my attempt to check if there are zero records returned.

```
$rowCount = 0;
foreach ($results as $record) {         
    $rowCount++;
}
if ($rowCount == 0) {
  // alert if no values
  $form['no_values'] = [
    '#markup' => $this->t('No entries exist.'),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="alert alert-warning my-5" role="alert">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];
  return $form;
}else{
  // the actual form
  $form[]...
  $content['row']['fname'] = [
    '#markup' => $this->t($fname),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="col-md-11">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];
  ...
  return $form;
};
```

Edit:
The error I get is because it seems to keep processing the page and it's looking for a variable that is in the else{} form.

```
Undefined variable: fname in Drupal\myModule\Controller\DbtngExampleController->entryView() (line 186 of modules/custom/myModule/src/Controller/DbtngExampleController.php).
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try emitting a warning via the messenger service like:

```
if ($rowCount == 0) {
  // Alert if no values.
  \Drupal::messenger()->addWarning($this->t('No entries exist.'));
}
```

And then you can just discard `form['no_values']`.

**UPDATE:**

For the additional error that you are facing, you appear to not have the `$fname` variable defined in your `else` clause. Try declaring it outside the if else statement ie. `$fname = '';` or similar. It is not clear to me what the use is of that variable or which value it should contain.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I updated my question and added info about the error I am getting.

Comment: Hi @jbreslow, I see you updated the question, but I don't see an error.

Comment: Error Should be there now.

Comment: Whoever downvoted care to explain?

Comment: Why is it going into the else, and generating the error, if there are no records? I do appreciate your help and it wasn't me that downvoted you.